# How can I maintain a client-side database without creating an extra file

Tags: c#, database

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to store data in my application without creating an external database file. Is this even possible? I'd like to keep it portable as just a singular executable file.

If this is possible, can someone link me to some sort of tutorial or guide or something? Just trying to get my feet wet.

Comment: This question will likely be closed, as it's not asking for an answer to a specific technical problem. For your needs, though, know that if you are going to persist (save) data, it must be saved somewhere. You could use a text file (xml, csv) on the client machine, the registry of the client machine (ideal for settings), an .ini file or a .settings file. If you want to query info like a database though, you will probably do better with a database

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured as much. I've been looking into creating SQL CE databases programmatically. I reckon I'll have to go to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database is read-only then you can include it as resource into your application. You cannot alter the exe file during runtime. If the db is read/write you must have an external file for it.

You could start with an empty db or a db containing default entries stored as resource inside the application and copy it to an external file when the application is started for the first time. At least, this would make the deployment easier.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is the default answer for client side databases.

Comment: "I'm trying to store data in my application **without creating an external database file**"

Comment: Read between the lines. He isn't asking for a magical storage location. What he wants is a "single executable", as in not telling the user to install and run MySQL or SQL Server, which would be a second executable.

Comment: The reason you need an external file or database of some sort is that the client would have to be able to recompile the code everytime changes are made. Ie save data